# multiple instances of gps activity is running at same time

Tags: android, android-intent, gps, android-pendingintent

I have got an app tracking GPS.

I am using `myLocationOverlay` to get location and I have got kind of navigation. 
there are two options when closing app.

1. gps keeps tracking (not calling `myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation;`)
2. gps is disabled.

when GPS keeps tracking it gives `Notifications` and when I click to the `Notification`, there is no problem, it opens the currently running activity with pending `Intent`.

But when I open the same activity again from the application, there appears a new instance of the same activity and it starts to use the `GPS` and updates the notification.

So two instances of same activity are working at the same time.
I tried to close the previous activity when second instance is opened but I couldn't do it.

I've also used `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` when opening new intent and also put this `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

in `AndroidManifest.xml`  but the first created one still works.

I hope someone has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP** in conjunction with **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**. When used together, these flags are a way of locating an existing activity in another task and putting it in a position where it can respond to the intent.

Comment: i did it but didn't change anything